# How to store values of QRect to list

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am using QRubberBand in PyQt4 where I am cropping the image. I need the all the coordinate values present in QRect such as x1,y1,x2,y2. Below are few function of mouse events for cropping the image.

```
def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent): 
    self.origin = QMouseEvent.pos()
    self.rubberband.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.origin, QtCore.QSize()) )
    self.rubberband.show()

def mouseMoveEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
    self.x = int(QMouseEvent.x())
    self.y = int(QMouseEvent.y())
    text1 = str(self.x)
    text2 = str(self.y)
    print self.x,self.y
    QtGui.QToolTip.showText(QMouseEvent.pos() , "X: "+text1+" "+"Y: "+text2,self)
    if self.rubberband.isVisible():
        self.rubberband.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.origin, QMouseEvent.pos()).normalized() & self.image.rect())

def cropImage(self,rect,QMouseEvent):
    self.image = self.image.copy(rect)
    self.pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.image))
    self.image.save(os.getcwd()+'/cropped.png')
    self.update()

def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
    if self.rubberband.isVisible():
        self.rubberband.hide()
        selected = []
        rect = self.rubberband.geometry()
        print rect
        self.cropImage(rect,QMouseEvent)
```

if I print rect, I am getting output as

```
PyQt4.QtCore.QRect(51, 122, 131, 185)
```

My interest is to save these QRect values in list for further processing.

Comment: You could save it in a list

Comment: I tried to save it in list and printed 2nd element. Getting error as 'QRect' object does not support indexing

Comment: What do you mean by second element?

Comment: I saved it in list named area = [] and tried to print area[1]

Comment: Python lists start with index 0

Comment: In `PyQt4.QtCore.QRect(51, 122, 131, 185)` do You want to get `51, 122, 131, 185`?

Comment: yes exactly I want to print individual element

Comment: see my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the following object `rect = QRect(x, y, w, h)` You can get each item with the following functions:

```
x = rect.x()
y = rect.y()
w = rect.width()
h = rect.height()
```

Example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
rect = QtCore.QRect(51, 122, 131, 185)
x = rect.x()
y = rect.y()
w = rect.width()
h = rect.height()
print(x, y, w, h)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped me a lot

Answer (score 4):

Use `getRect()` method of `QRect`:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect

rect = QRect(51, 122, 131, 185)
print(rect.getRect())
```

prints `(51, 122, 131, 185)`